# Using Python to Script Illustrator: Saving an EPS File (COM Variant)

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, pywin32, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to save an Illustrator file as a .eps using Python. As far as I'm aware Python is not supported normally for Illustrator so I downloaded a reference file which I imported to my code. Usually the code is very similar to the javascript used in Illustrator.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "s:\Workstation - DavidK\Code\Main\SAVETEST.py", line 12, in <module>

doc.SaveAs(SaveIn = 'S:/Workstation - DavidK/Code/Main/DeleteLater/tempSheet.eps', Options = saveOpts)

File "s:\Workstation - DavidK\Code\Main\illustrator_ref.py", line 1998, in SaveAs

 

return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1398161747, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((8, 1), (12, 17)),SaveIn

 TypeError: Objects of type 'EPSSaveOptions' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT (but obtaining the buffer() of this object could)
```

I've tried using buffer but I'm using Python3 so it'd have to memoryview which requires bytes and I don't understand that at all.

Here's my code:

```
from illustrator_ref import *
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import DispatchBaseClass
from win32com.client import CoClassBaseClass

app = win32.GetActiveObject("Illustrator.Application")
doc = app.activeDocument

saveOpts = EPSSaveOptions(CoClassBaseClass)
saveOpts.EmbedAllFonts = True
saveOpts.SaveMultipleArtboards = True
doc.SaveAs(SaveIn = 'S:/Workstation - DavidK/Code/Main/DeleteLater/tempSheet.eps', Options = saveOpts)
```

Here's the illustrator_ref code I'm having trouble understanding:

```
# This CoClass is known by the name 'Illustrator.EPSSaveOptions.24'
class EPSSaveOptions(CoClassBaseClass): # A CoClass
    # Options which may be supplied when saving a document as an Illustrator EPS file
    CLSID = IID('{99D7941A-05F9-419A-BA50-4C6148B54187}')
    coclass_sources = [
    ]
    coclass_interfaces = [
        _EPSSaveOptions,
    ]
    default_interface = _EPSSaveOptions

class _EPSSaveOptions(DispatchBaseClass):
    'Options which may be supplied when saving a document as an Illustrator EPS file'
    CLSID = IID('{95CD20A7-AD72-11D3-B086-0010A4F5C335}')
    coclass_clsid = IID('{99D7941A-05F9-419A-BA50-4C6148B54187}')

    def SetObjectValue(self, arg0=defaultUnnamedArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(0, LCID, 8, (24, 0), ((9, 0),),arg0
            )

    _prop_map_get_ = {
        # Method 'Application' returns object of type '_Application'
        "Application": (1667330160, 2, (9, 0), (), "Application", '{95CD20AA-AD72-11D3-B086-0010A4F5C335}'),
        "ArtboardRange": (1884304483, 2, (8, 0), (), "ArtboardRange", None),
        "CMYKPostScript": (1883459667, 2, (11, 0), (), "CMYKPostScript", None),
        "Compatibility": (1883849584, 2, (3, 0), (), "Compatibility", None),
        "CompatibleGradientPrinting": (1883457360, 2, (11, 0), (), "CompatibleGradientPrinting", None),
        "EmbedAllFonts": (1883586886, 2, (11, 0), (), "EmbedAllFonts", None),
        "EmbedLinkedFiles": (1883861065, 2, (11, 0), (), "EmbedLinkedFiles", None),
        "FlattenOutput": (1884243564, 2, (3, 0), (), "FlattenOutput", None),
        "IncludeDocumentThumbnails": (1883849588, 2, (11, 0), (), "IncludeDocumentThumbnails", None),
        "JapaneseFileFormat": (1883924070, 2, (11, 0), (), "JapaneseFileFormat", None),
        "Overprint": (1883131728, 2, (3, 0), (), "Overprint", None),
        "PostScript": (1884312428, 2, (3, 0), (), "PostScript", None),
        "Preview": (1634291798, 2, (3, 0), (), "Preview", None),
        "SaveMultipleArtboards": (1397571938, 2, (11, 0), (), "SaveMultipleArtboards", None),
    }
    _prop_map_put_ = {
        "ArtboardRange": ((1884304483, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "CMYKPostScript": ((1883459667, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "Compatibility": ((1883849584, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "CompatibleGradientPrinting": ((1883457360, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "EmbedAllFonts": ((1883586886, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "EmbedLinkedFiles": ((1883861065, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "FlattenOutput": ((1884243564, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "IncludeDocumentThumbnails": ((1883849588, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "JapaneseFileFormat": ((1883924070, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "ObjectValue": ((0, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "Overprint": ((1883131728, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "PostScript": ((1884312428, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "Preview": ((1634291798, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "SaveMultipleArtboards": ((1397571938, LCID, 4, 0),()),
    }
    # Default method for this class is 'ObjectValue'
    def __call__(self, arg0=defaultUnnamedArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(0, LCID, 8, (24, 0), ((9, 0),),arg0
            )

    def __unicode__(self, *args):
        try:
            return unicode(self.__call__(*args))
        except pythoncom.com_error:
            return repr(self)
    def __str__(self, *args):
        return str(self.__unicode__(*args))
    def __int__(self, *args):
        return int(self.__call__(*args))
    def __iter__(self):
        "Return a Python iterator for this object"
        try:
            ob = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(-4,LCID,3,(13, 10),())
        except pythoncom.error:
            raise TypeError("This object does not support enumeration")
        return win32com.client.util.Iterator(ob, None)
```

The reference file can be downloaded here if you'd like to try and reproduce the problem: https://github.com/lohriialo/illustrator-scripting-python/tree/master/api_reference

Comment: I'm getting the same error (Windows 7, Illustrator CS6). And I have no idea how to fix it. It's a pity that the author of the api_reference provided no examples how to use it (besides the non-relevant basic 'hello world' which doesn't even need this api at all).

Comment: Yeah, so far I've gotten around it by writing a few lines in javascript which saves as an eps with a temp name and running that script through python, then changing the filename with python

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Dispatch method from win32com.client, and know the name of the object you're working with, you can create illustrator objects in python and treat them the same as any other.  Here's a simple program I wrote, running in python 3.12.0 and Win 10, that show's how it's done, hope this helps:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import constants as win_const

"""
Module Docstring
"""

__author__ = "Jonathan M."
__version__ = "0.1.0"
__license__ = "MIT"

def main():
    """ Main entry point of the app """

    PATH_MAPPING = {
        "input_path" : r"-PUT YOUR INPUT PATH HERE-",
        "output_path" : r"-PUT YOUR OUTPUT PATH HERE-"
        }
    
    print("Starting")
    # Grab the Adobe Illustrator Application.
    try:
        adobe_app = win32.GetActiveObject("Illustrator.Application")
    except:
        adobe_app = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Illustrator.Application")
        adobe_app.UserInteractionLevel = -1 #set DONTDISPLAYALERT flag
    
    for file_to_convert in os.listdir(PATH_MAPPING["input_path"]):
    
        adobe_app.Open(os.path.join(PATH_MAPPING["input_path"], file_to_convert))
        adobe_doc = adobe_app.ActiveDocument
        
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file_to_convert)
        
        #we don't need to specify a file extension, illustrator will do that for us
        save_as_path = os.path.join(PATH_MAPPING["output_path"], f"{filename}")
        
        save_options = win32.Dispatch("Illustrator.epsSaveOptions")
        save_options.EmbedAllFonts = True
        save_options.SaveMultipleArtboards = True
        
        adobe_doc.SaveAs(save_as_path, save_options)

        #Close the document without saving
        adobe_doc.Close(win_const.aiDoNotSaveChanges)
    
    if adobe_app is not None:
        try:
            adobe_app.Application.Quit()
        except Exception as err:
            os.system("taskkill /f /im  Illustrator.exe")
    
    print("Done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """ This is executed when run from the command line """
    main()
```